# Enum and polymorphism in Java, playing cards example

Tags: java, interface, enums, polymorphism

I try to design a project about playing cards. I have a class Card

```
class Card 
{
     Rank rank; 
     Suit suit;
}
```

The Suit is an enum.

```
  enum Suit { .... }
```

Rank should have a method getValue().
I would like to have more than one Ranks, ie. BlackJackRank and PokerRank. So I created an interface Rank with the method getValue and two enums BlackJackRank and PokerRank which implement this interface.

```
enum BlackJackRank implements Rank
{
   ACE(1),DEUCE(2),THREE(3) ....
   private final int value;
   private BackJackRank(int value) { ... }

   @Override
   public int getValue() { ... }
}
```

My problem is that I can't call the rank.name() and rank.ordinal() in the Card class because Rank is not enum. Any idea?

Comment: What is the responsibility of `BlackJackRank`? Why do you like to model them as `enum`? Perhaps we may solve your problem if we understand what you like to achieve, besides the Java implementation of it. Besides: `enum.values() is an enum type exclusive method, like a static method, which is available only for the type you call it at`.

Comment: What is a better approach here is dependency injection, if you care enough to learn it.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski: care to elaborate?

Comment: If you need that method in your interface, just add it.

Comment: @Harmlezz My mistake, the rank.values was a bad example. The rank.name() and rank.ordinal() are methods that I would like in the Card class.

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis Why would you need `rank.ordinal()`? I believe this method shouldn't be used (in most cases when we think we need it).

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis Why would you need to call `values()` on an instance of `Rank`? If you're in such a place where you want the list of possible values, then you probably know what list you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now after you changed the question, here is the answer which should work:

```
class Card<T extends Enum<T> & Rank> {

    private final T rank;

    public Card(T rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getRankOrdinal() {
        return rank.ordinal();
    }

    public int getRankValue() {
        return rank.getValue();
    }
}

interface Rank {
    public int getValue();
}

enum BlackJackRank implements Rank {

    ACE(1);

    private final int value;

    private BlackJackRank(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```